# How to link between Dropdownlist and a Image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to make a link between DropDownList items and a changeable Image such that when I choose the "Background Image" (I have a DropDownList have multiple called Background Image) as Flowers, a photo of flower would appear in the Image.

When I choose the "Background Image" as Valentine the Image will change to a Valentine photo.

http://www.mediafire.com/view/xdyp45iqdva8011/2.png
http://www.mediafire.com/view/dnvrxj569x92jyg/3.png

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you or suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: if u want a program Ask it's here (How to link Between the DropDownList and AN Image ?) , and if u don't got it as i think it's the Description (see back of) and if u still didn't got it simply download the two photos related to my ASK ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows Form:**

Here is how you do it with a ComboBox and a PictureBox:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.Equals("Flowers"))
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("<path to Flower's picture>");
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.Equals("Valentine"))
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("<path to Valentine's picture>");
}
```

**Edit:**

**ASP.NET:**

This can be done in an ASP.NET application as well by setting the value of your drop down list options to the URLs of the images you want each of them to show and passing those values as the source to your image.

Here is how. Add this in your .aspx source:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="20px" Width="200px">
    <asp:ListItem Value="<Place your image URL here>">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="<Place your image URL here>">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="<Place your image URL here>">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="550px" />
```

And add this to your .aspx.cs code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs
{
    Image image = this.Image1;
    image.ImageUrl = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
}
```

This will change the image based on the value selected in the drop down list.

Comment: thank u but ur code is Widows Form but mine is C# Asp.net ,,,, But i want to do the same what's the code means :) if u can give me more help

Comment: @user3748702 I have edited my answer to include the solution for ASP.NET. Let me know if it helps you :)

Comment: i think u got it but i have an awful error now :( .... see that
https://www.mediafire.com/?4ectv1y2wbxa1uu

Comment: i answered the  back error but i still have a small problem
when i choose any Item of the DropDownList i get no Image
the photos doesn't appear
but by the way Really Many thx

Comment: You're welcome. Can you update the question with the code you tried? I might be able to help you better if I have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, string>` to link between the selected item and an image source.

e.g.

```
public ActionResult Index(string selectedValue)
{
    var imageBySelection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    imageBySelection.Add("Flowers", "http://www.mediafire.com/view/xdyp45iqdva8011/2.png");
    imageBySelection.Add("Valentine", "http://www.mediafire.com/view/dnvrxj569x92jyg/3.png");

    return View(imageBySelection[selectedValue]);
}
```

In view:

```
@model string

<img src="@Model" />
```

Comment: thx but ur code is VB.Net not C#.Net

Comment: @user3748702 I'm pretty sure it's C#.